# ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/libexec/java_home (Mac OSX)

Tags: react-native, java-home

When I run `react-native run-android` I get the error `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/libexec/java_home`.

I add the Java home path to my bash profile like this:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`.

When I paste this and hit enter in the terminal:

`/usr/libexec/java_home`,

I get this:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`.

But when I run `react-native run-android`, I still get the error.

It's driving me absolutely mad and I don't know how to fix it.

Any ideas hugely appreciated.

Comment: what do you get if you type echo $JAVA_HOME ?

Answer (score 6):

Set the value you get.

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`

```
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```